# How do we add a "RS" symbol before the user input value? in PEGA

Tags: pega

I want to add an "RS" symbol before the input. I can use edit input but it’s very costly as the change is getting reflected after performing. So, are there any options we can use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Currency` UI control instead of `Integer`, `Text` or `Decimal` on the section for that property.

Then in presentation tab of the control do below changes:-

In `Read-Only Format`, select `Symbol` vale as `Constant`.

In `Symbol constant`, put value as `RS`. Not only `RS`, you can paste `₹` symbol also.

In `Position`, select `left`.

In `Editable Format` part check the check box `Display value using read-only formatting`.